# How I send a data from child form to parent MDI form or parent MDI from to child form in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a value(let CompanyId) in a child form. I want to pass this value in a level of the MDI parent form.

In child form I retrieve data from database in a datagrid view.
Now I select a value from datagrid view.

string SkillName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["SHORTS"].Value.ToString();

Now I want to pass this SkillName value to MDI parent form.
How Can I do this?

Comment: Can you show what you did so far to solve this?

Comment: In child form I retrieve data from database in a datagrid view.
Now I select a value from datagrid view.

string SkillName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["SHORTS"].Value.ToString();

Now I want to pass this SkillName value to MDI parent form.
How Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are literally countless ways to do it. it all depend on what you want to do and why.
@f0x way is good, but also use a public parameter, create an event and pop it when you want, set a flag(could be a global flag) and more.

if you want to pass simple data from parent to child you can do it by, as f0x said, in the constructor, or make the child register an event you execute, that send a string/int/etc., and then you can execute the event whenever you(the parent) want and the child immediately handle that data.

it can go the other way around: when the parent create the child, it register on an event the child fire...

here is an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

  public void RegisterSon()
  {
     ChildForm frm = new ChildForm();
     frm.MyEventChild += new MyEvntHndler(frm_MyEventChild);
  }

  void frm_MyEventChild(string data)
  {

  }
}

public delegate void MyEvntHndler(string data);

public class ChildForm: Form
{
  public event MyEvntHndler MyEventChild;

  private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (MyEventChild != null)
     {
        MyEventChild("This is my data");
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to pass the `companyId` as a parameter to the constructor of the form.

For example in the company form:

```
public partial class CompanyForm : Form
{
    public CompanyForm(int companyId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When you call the new form simply pass the value from your calling form:

```
var form = new CompanyForm(10); // '10' the id 
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Show();
```